# Error Handling Paradigms: Mixing Exceptions and Error Codes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dll, exception, error-handling

I'm currently developing a game engine in C++ using various pieces of middleware including OGRE (graphics), Bullet (physics), and OpenAL (sound), and I'm fairly early on in the project. It's at this point that I'm setting up my error handling mechanisms.

I plan on exposing the engine to the user by containing it within a DLL and exporting a function which will return a pointer to the main engine object. This object will contain methods with which you can access various components of the engine - most objects will be accessed via interfaces so that the user is hidden from the actual implementations.

I'm inclined to use error codes as my error reporting mechanism instead of exceptions since

1. Passing exceptions through the DLL link increases the complexity of error reporting, forces me to export the exception classes, etc., and
2. Error codes are generally more efficient, and for this reason they are common in real-time game engines.

The only issue that arises then is one with constructors - they can't return error codes. I therefore plan on using error codes for all methods, but throwing exceptions when constructors fail. Since I plan on using the factory method pattern to generate objects and pass them to user code, the exceptions would be handled internally by the engine, and the user would just get a null pointer on construction failure. I realize that you usually shouldn't mix exceptions and return codes, but the alternatives don't sound any better:

- You could not do anything in the constructor and use some kind of init() method, but there goes RAII.
- You could set a flag and have some kind of isOk() or isInitialized() method, but now you've introduced the possibility of some zombie state where the object exists but failed to initialize, and you might forget to check to make sure it's alive.

I'm aware of the inherent costs and benefits of both systems, and realize that it's generally a bad idea to mix the two. However, since constructors can't have some kind of return value, would it be unreasonable throw exceptions when constructors fail and use error codes elsewhere? Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Why use a DLL? Why not  a static library?

Comment: @unaperson: flexibility, modularity, "recommendedness", it's a library used by several apps, etc... Why not use a DLL?

Comment: Re flag for error in constructor: Well, error codes are equally vulnerable to being overlooked.

Comment: @rubenvb Static libraries do all that. DLLs are an answer to a 20-year old problem (limited disk space) that no longer really exists.

Comment: If you never propagate the exception out of your internal factory code, then what's the problem?  You aren't mixing exceptions with error codes, because nobody ever sees your exceptions.

Comment: @unaperson: no they don't: you can't replace a static library with an updated version without replacing all apps linked to it, you can't share the same memory for one instance of a static library (each app linked to it will have its own copy of the library), for big projects: you'll have to completely relink all code instead of only relinking the DLLs. Surely I don't have to link to stuff like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_link_library#Features_of_DLL. I'm not saying DLLs are the best, I'm just saying they still solve a different problem.

Comment: @rubenvb - But what are the odds that you run several games at once, all using the same game engine?

Comment: @Bo: true. My point was only to keep an open mind. No need to force someone to use a static library. And there's still the easier updating by replacing one smaller file instead of the whole game. But that's beside my point.

Comment: Everyone's made insightful points. I think I'm going to go with a static library so I can use exceptions without hassle, though I may eventually split subsystems into DLLs. Thanks!

Comment: @nbt "DLLs are an answer to a 20-year old problem" - no they arent. Stable binary interfaces between code that might be build by entirely different organizations and modularization have a immense value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer exceptions (and have many good reasons for that). But of course throwing exceptions from DLL code to user code (and vice versa) is a bad idea. So in your situation I would use exceptions within modules (both DLLs and executable) and use error_return-based APIs for DLL exports. When using DLL's error_return-based API I would use exception-based wrappers for those error_return-ing functions.

IMO returning error indicators in any way (by return value or through reference or via per-thread error codes) havily messes the code with endless error-checking branches. My way (and my understanding of C++ way) is returning only in a case of success.

Comment: Excellent suggestion for handling exceptions within the DLL. However, you've made such a strong point about the endless condition checking caused by error codes that I think I'll make the engine a static library so that I can properly use exceptions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd say screw RAII and use Init methods.  Mixing two paradigms not only decreases consistency, it also forces your Engine's consumers to implement Exception handling mechanisms when some would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer now to only work with exceptions, but if you still need or want to use error codes with constructors a aproach that I like is to force the user to pass a parameter in constructor:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int &errorCode) {
            //our init code
            rc = SOMETHING_BAD;
        }
};

//on a method or function:
int errorCode;
Foo foo(errorCode);
if(errorCode != RESULT_OK)
{
      //handle it
}
```

I think this is better than having a IsOk() method or a separated Init method, because it at least force the user to pass a variable as parameter and it is hard to forget to check errors, the downside is that sometime it is boring to declare variables just for that.

My 2 cents.